# probability distribution, discrete random variable

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

So I was given a practice midterm but I got stuck on this problem, I don't understand why or how the answers came up, or even if they are right. For the most part, I have trouble understanding where the 2 and -2 came from in the solution of a.

**The probability distribution of a discrete random variable X is given by**

**P(X=-1)= 1/5,  P(X=0)= 2/5,  P(X=1)= 2/5,**

**a. Compute E[X].**

**b. Give the probability distribution of Y = X^2 and compute E[Y] using the distribution of Y.**

**c. Determine E[X^2] using the change-of-variable formula. Check your answer against the answer from part (b).**

**d. Determine Var(X).**

Solutions:

a) E[X]= −2×2/5 + 0×2/5 + 2×2/5 = 2/5

b) The probability mass function of Y=X^2 is
Y=X^2     0    1
P(Y=k)   2/5  3/5
Then, 
E[Y] = 0(2/5) + 2(3/5) = (3/5)

c) Using the change-of-variable, we have 
E[Y] = (-2)^2 (3/5) + 0^2 (2/5) + 2^2 (2/5) = 3/5

d) Since E[X^2] = E[Y] = 5/5, then Var[X] = E[X^3]-(E[X])^3 = 3/5 - (1/5)^3 = 14/35

Comment: The solution is incorrect.

Comment: The variance of $X$ is $E(X^2)-(E(X))^2$.

Answer (score 1):

There is a typo somewhere. The problem as stated should use -1 and 1 instead of -2 and 2.

Comment: so the answer for part a would be 1/5? and then following that fix everything else related to it, in the other parts.

Comment: Yes, if the probability distribution of $X$ is $P(X=-1)= 1/5$, $P(X=0)= 2/5$, and $P(X=1)= 2/5$, then $E(X)=-1\cdot\frac{1}{5}+0\cdot\frac{2}{5}+1\cdot\frac{2}{5}=\frac{1}{5}$. Also, in part (d) there seems to be a typo as variance in $E(X^2)-(E(X))^2$ not the 3rd power.